# How do I get the lyrics of the currently playing song in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am getting the Current Song playing as an MPMediaItem and I can successfully retrieve the title, artist and song length. However when I try to get the lyrics nothing shows up in the text field that I am updating.

```
let currentSong: MPMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0]

if let artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork = currentSong.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as? MPMediaItemArtwork {
    albumArtwork.image = artwork.image(at: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120))
    songTitle.text = currentSong.title
    songArtist.text = currentSong.artist
    songLength.text = currentSong.playbackDuration.stringFromTimeInterval()
    songLyrics.text = currentSong.lyrics

}
```

I want songLyrics.text to be equal to the lyrics of the song.

Comment: Are you sure that your song has the lyrics embedded in its metadata? It doesn't have to, that's why most of `MPMediaItem` properties are optionals.

Comment: Do you know how to check if they have values or not?

Comment: did you get any solution to this?

Comment: @YogeshPatel Unfortuantely I pinned the project back then, however since then I've gained more programming experience, I would recommend just checking its type/value to see if it's null or length == 0. (Something along those lines)